# Template hook_preprocess_page not being called after duplicating website

Tags: theming, hooks

I'me trying to duplicate a drupal website, using Druplal 7's multisite feature :

- I made a custom website folder (sites/site2.com) with correct settings.php for db
- I used backup & restore to transfer db content from site1 to site2
- I duplicated the theme (/sites/all/themes/site1theme to sites/all/themes/site2theme)
- I edited the theme.info, and changed the hooks in template.php (site2theme_ ...) to match the new theme name

The front page is loading correctly, except that there is no CSS (and possibly some JS missing maybe)

template.php has a site2theme_preprocess_page function, whith some drupal_add_css() methods, but it looks like the hook function is not being called.

I've probably forgotten things in my website duplication process, and I'd be happy if you could give me some leads.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have tried clearing cache specifically for Drupal site2.

Comment: Of course I did that but ...

Reading your comment, I wanted to make sure & did it again and after a full refresh of the page... it's working great as expected....

Honestly dunno how I missed that. I'm 100% sure I purged it... That was my 1st idea...

Anyway, sorry for wasting ppl time with something so obivous :(

Comment: No worries. Happens. Keep calm and clear cache :)